# Why are JOINS deprecated for a in-memory database?

Tags: architecture, database, enterprise-architecture, scalability

Correct me if I'm misunderstanding. Refer to the following sentence:

> Stack Overflow copied a key part of the Wikipedia database design.
>   This turned out to be a mistake which will need massive and painful
>   database refactoring to fix. **The refactorings will be to avoid
>   excessive joins in a lot of key queries.** This is the key lesson from
>   giant multi-terabyte table schemas (like Google’s BigTable) which are
>   completely join-free. **This is significant because Stack Overflow's
>   database is almost completely in RAM and the joins still exact too
>   high a cost.**<sup>1</sup>

Actually I'm trying to pass from the interest on single technology like Asp.net MVC to architectures design.

Can you better clarify the quoted sentence?

<sup>[1]</sup> http://highscalability.com/stack-overflow-architecture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misread the directionality of the quote.

JOINs are *generally* discouraged for high-volume systems, because they are expensive (because of I/O being necessary more than one table). SO put their database into RAM specifically to avoid being hit by double disk I/O costs, and it turns out that *even* without physical I/O, the double table searching is still too slow. That shows you just how inefficient JOINs are on large volumes of data.

Comment: But that's impressive... How can it be? A similar sentence seems to show that relational database are not enough efficient on one of their primary task.. (handling 3NF).. I think it really worths a question here..